# Nested dict in D-bus signals

Tags: python, dbus

There is class

```
class MyService(dbus.service.Object):
  def __init__(self):
    bus_name = dbus.service.BusName(__dbus_object_name__, bus=dbus.SessionBus())
    dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, __dbus_object_path__)

  @dbus.service.signal(__dbus_object_name__, signature='a{sv}')
  def TickSignal(self, info):
    print(info)
s = MyService()
```

try to send nested dictionaties

s.TickSignal({'a': 'b', 'b': 1, 'c': {'a':'a' }}) works fine but if nested dict contais a number cause exception

s.TickSignal({'a': 'b', 'b': 1, 'c' :{'a':'a', 'b':1 }})

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sig.py", line 26, in <module>
    s.TickSignal({'a': 'b', 'b': 1, 'c':{'a':'a', 'b':1}})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/decorators.py", line 314, in emit_signal
    message.append(signature=signature, *args)
TypeError: Expected a string or unicode object
```

Answer (score 0):

The D-Bus binding you are using (dbus-python) will assume all types in dictionaries are the same as an arbitrary item in the dictionary, if no signature is explicitly specified. In this case dbus-python makes the assumption that all items in the dictionary will be 'ss'.

From the [dbus-python tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#container-types):

> Dictionaries are represented by Python dictionaries, or by dbus.Dictionary, a subclass of dict. When sending a dictionary, if an introspected signature is available, that will be used; otherwise, if the signature keyword parameter was passed to the Dictionary constructor, that will be used to determine the contents' key and value signatures; otherwise, dbus-python will guess from an arbitrary item of the dict.

So you need to indicate what types are in the dictionary. One way to explicitly specify the signature is to create the data like this:

```
inner = dbus.Dictionary({'a': 'a', 'b': 1}, signature='sv')
outer = dbus.Dictionary({'a': 'b', 'b': 1, 'c': inner}, signature='sv')
s.TickSignal(outer)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested dictionary like this:

```
self._properties = dbus.Dictionary({
            'Metadata': dbus.Dictionary({
                'mpris:length': dbus.Int64(2400000000),
                'mpris:artUrl': 'file:///home/user/1.jpg',
                'xesam:artist': ['1', '2'],
                'xesam:title': 'hello world',
                'xesam:url': '',
                'xesam:album': 'hehe'
            }, signature='sv'),
            'CanControl': True
        }, signature='sv')
```

It should work.